# Which one will be better to join startup or service based

Tags: companies

I am MTech from CSE branch and a fresher. I have 2 offers one in service based company and other one is startup though package is same for both. I am really confused which company should I choose. Startup is currently working on charting JavaScript library like kendoUI and the startup is started about 2and half year back. But I am confused which one would be better for career growth. Because job profile also matters and as I am a fresher I don't know what to do. Can you please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you are looking for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ . Good luck!